# password_hash with salt does nothing

Tags: php, salt, password-hash

I am trying to generate a hash of a password but when I add the option salt to password_hash, it just does nothing.

The following line works properly.

```
    $pwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

But at the moment of me adding $options, it doesn't generate the hash.

```
    $options = array('salt' => 'whatever');
    $pwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
```

I have tried PASSWORD_BCRYPT but it doesn't work either.

If the option is ('cost' => 12) there are no problems at all.

I know it has been deprecated in PHP 7 but my version is 5.5.38, where it is supposed to be working. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What does that mean, "it doesn't generate the hash"? What exactly *does* it return? `null`? The unchanged input?

Comment: `Warning: password_hash(): Provided salt is too short: 8 expecting 22`

Comment: The fact that you're running PHP 5.5 doesn't mean that you should be doing this ...

Comment: yep, it just does nothing. But hassan gave me the hint I needed. My 'salt' was too short. with "whateverwhateverwhatever" works perfectly.

Comment: You do know that a salt is must to be unique for each password? If it is not unique it is not a salt. The best is to not provide any and let password_hash create the salt for you

Comment: Since the function `password_hash()` exists, it generates a cryptographically safe salt on its own, regarding all restrictions for the given algorithm. There was never a reason to pass a user defined salt and it should be avoided.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but this is for testing porpuses only, so we don't mind if the salt if the same for each password (actually we want it to be the same).